# Lower Central series example

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was wondering if anyone could offer a simple example or explanation of the lower central series.

I know the commutator subgroup of $G$ is defined as $[G,G]= \big< [x,y]|x,y \in G \big>$ However, since $[G,G]=G'$ must have smaller order than $G$, so I am unsure as to how to construct $[G,G']$.

In specific, if $[G,G']=\big<[x,y] \big | x \in G, y\in G' \big > $ does $x \in G, y\in G'$ imply all $x \in G$ and all $y \in G'$. Because all $y \in G'$ would not be all $x \in G$

More generally I think my question is how we can have a commutator of two subgroups of different order? How would we construct the pairs $[x,y]$ if there exist more $x$ than $y$

Sorry if this question is confusing. I think I just really need to see a concrete example that will illuminate some of the misconceptions I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $[G,G']=\langle [x,y] : \forall x\in G, \forall y\in G'\rangle$. A standard example to look at is $G=Q_8$. It is a straight forward exercise to see that $G'=Z(G)$, the center. So You get 
$$ G \geq [G,G]=G'=Z(G) \geq [G,G'] = [G,Z(G)]=1,$$ 
which looks like
$$ Q_8 \geq \langle -1\rangle \geq 1.$$

Edit: In response to your edit, if you want to naively compute the generators by hand, you would have to write out $\vert G \vert \cdot \vert G'\vert $ elements of the form $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$ assuming you don't care about repetition.

This is the same idea as computing $HK$ for normal subgroups $H,K\leq G$.

Comment: Thank you! I think I answered my own question while typing it, but I appreciate the example